# file reverts back to last commit after 24h using filesystem

Tags: git, node.js, heroku, github, filesystems

I'm using filesystem in Node.js to create files and edit them.
The problem is that after 24h the files revert back to the last commit.

Is fileSystem temporary?

How can I add files to my repository using filesystem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Heroku's filesystem is [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). You need to store your files on an external data store, such as Postgresql, S3, MongoDB, or many others. I highly recommend reading the [12 factor app](http://12factor.net/) to understand the thinking behind this.

Comment: also just to add - when the application is restarted (which Heroku do periodically as you're seeing here) then a fresh version of the slug is deployed which won't contain the uploaded item.

Comment: Yes, Heroku reboots all dynos once per day.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've used Amazon S3 and Cloudfront.

Answer (score -2):

The file system repository allows access to files which have been uploaded via FTP  into designated folders on the server.
When a file from the file system repository is re-used elsewhere on Moodle,it has the option to make a copy (a new, unconnected version) or to create a shortcut .

Also you can  refer this below link...

> http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Working_with_files